Is BugMeNot's DATABASE QUERY ERROR expected on success?
I tried to share the login of my Geometry Dash account that I cannot delete, on BugMeNot.
I got this (error?) message:

Login details are here, if it matters:
Username: nongmailuser
Password: DELETEDMYGMAILACC

As you can probably guess by the login details, I can't access the email address associated with the account, because I deleted my Gmail account.
The "share it" hyperlinks on both the boomlings.com and geometrydash.com pages throw this error when I press the "Submit Query" button
Was this submission successful?
EDIT: I've readded Gmail to my Google account, to the email address with Mojira, because my other emails failed and will delete the Geometry Dash account, but my question still stands.
